# What is the name of the area of skin between the nose and the upper lip / mouth?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the name of the area that is between the nose and the upper lip, circled in figure 1 below?

[image]

<sup>[source of face image](http://www.uni-regensburg.de/Fakultaeten/phil_Fak_II/Psychologie/Psy_II/beautycheck/english/durchschnittsgesichter/durchschnittsgesichter.htm)</sup>

I have found that the area circled in figure 2, the small indentation under the nose, is called the "philtrum," which is what the many searches I have tried have yielded, but I cannot figure out what the entire area is called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [upper lip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_lip), the image below is from the wiki entry on [philtrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philtrum).

[image: Image of the Face]

Comment: Okay, but then what is the "top half" of the lip called? The "upper lip" seems to me that it is referring to the part of the lip right above the mouth.

Comment: That's... quite a strange name. Is there any word that more commonly refers to each of these?

Comment: @Doorknob - Elliot has named it correctly. The upper lip is skin-covered, skin-colored, and hairy. The pink parts are called the upper and lower vermilion, the border between the skin and the vermilion is called the vermilion border, the wet, shiny inner portion of what people call the "lips" is called the wet vermilion or the mucosa. So, you see, Elliot has given you the accurate response. How do I know? From studying the [anatomy](http://www.med.unc.edu/surgery/plastic/grabb/Chapter%2036.pdf) of the lips, having had to suture lip lacerations about a couple hundred times.

Comment: Actually, OP is asking the name of the upper half of the upper lip. There is no specific name for that.

Comment: It is sometimes called "upper cutaneous lip" or "cutaneous upper lip" though. Because that is the skin part of the upper lip.

Comment: @medica: I don't think so. Upper lip = upper skin part + upper vermilion

Comment: @medica: Even the link that you gave explains vermilion reconstruction under upper lip section. I checked other technical sources as well. I want to agree with you because your field is medicine but I'm still not convinced.

Comment: @medica: As I said, even the link that you gave agrees with me. It says "upper-lip vermilion" and "vermilion in the upper lip". What am I missing here?

Comment: @ermanen it says that the *lip* consists of four components, two of which are the skin and the vermilion,  it then describes the lips as being similar to facial skin in as much as hair grows on it. The hairless pinkish section is called *vermilion*, which is not listed in the diagram above but is clearly shown in the link.

Comment: @medica, what then is the upper lip (the skin-covered bit) and the upper vermilion called, seen as one, i.e., from the nasolabial fold all the way down to the bottom of the upper vermilion?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - the entire flap, from the edge of the gums to the bottom of the nose, and everything in between (fat, muscle, blood vessels, etc.) is called the lip. The hand starts at the wrist crease and extends to the fingertips. Do fingernails have no separate name, but are just part of the digits? The whole thing is called the hand. The whole thing is called the lip. The upper lip is the skin surface. The vermilion is the pink or brown part. Anatomically, things are distinct. It's like denying nails exist ("They're called *nail-colored* fingers"). OP was correctly answered by Elliot.

Comment: @medica, but ‘lip’ can be either the upper or lower one—how does one distinguish the upper part of the whole lip area (gums to nose) from the lower one (gums to chin) without mixing it up with the parts that don’t include the vermilia? The hands are not, as far as I can tell, quite parallel, because ‘left hand’ doesn’t refer to, say, the carpals and metacarpals seen together. (I’m not mistrusting your answer, by the way, just being curious if there even is a word. I don’t know of any word for the carpals and metacarpals as one, either, for example.)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: What you say agrees with me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - The carpals and metacarpals form the palm, which has a ventral surface, a dorsal surface (also known as *the back of ones hand*), the intrinsic palmar muscles, and other tissue. It's a hand. There are digits, there is the palm. the digits are part of the hand, but not part of the palm. Does knowing that bit make my explanation any clearer?

Comment: @medica, hmmm, no, not really. I feel I'm not expressing myself very well. Colloquially, _upper lip_ refers to the upper vermilion. Medically, to the part above the upper vermilion. Those definitions use ‘upper’ in two different senses (the upper one vs. the upper part). Together, they form, as you say, the _lip_. But if this _lip_ is to be distinguished from its jaw-attached counterpart below, one would almost have to call it _upper lip_, except that already means two different things, just like I presume _lower lip_ does. [cont'd -->]

Comment: [--> cont'd] Ideally, there'd be a separate word for _upper lip and vermilion_ that wasn't just _upper lip_ (which is already ambiguous if you don't know whether the context is medical or colloquial, and would be doubly ambiguous if it had to serve this third meaning also). That was what I was wondering if there was.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Like the maxillary arch? As opposed to the mandibular arch? Honestly, I feel like this has diverged into medical territory. Anyway, from the definition of Philtrum: The philtrum is a vertical groove in the middle area of the upper lip, common to many mammals, extending from **the nose to the upper lip**.

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting question because there is no simple answer. One of the challenges in answering it is that 'lips' and 'lower/upper lip' refer to different things.

### Lips

There seems to be broad agreement on what 'lips' (plural) means. They refer to the pink part, which you'd apply lip balsem or lipstick to.

### Upper lip, lower lip

There is less agreement about 'lower/upper lip'. The accepted definition is that these words refer to both the pink and the skin-colored part. But this is a larger area than what 'lips' means, so that obviously leads to confusion, because a lot of people use 'upper/lower lip' to refer to only the pink part.

### Cutaneous lip

So, we've been talking about 'just the pink part' and 'both the pink part and the skin-colored part'. What about 'just the skin-colored part'? In colloquial English, there is no dedicated word for that. So let's settle for a scientific or medical term. "The skin-colored part of the lip" is called the **cutaneous lip**.

So the best answer to the original question would be **cutaneous upper lip**.

### Summary

- **Lips** usually refer to just the 'pink' parts.
- **Lip** usually refers to a larger area:
- **Upper lip** is everything between the mouth opening and the base of the nose.
- **Lower lip** is everything between the mouth opening and the chin.
- **Vermilion zone** is the pink, non-wet part of the lips.
- **Cutaneous lip** is the skin-colored part of the lips.
- **Philtrum** is a vertical subsection of the cutaneous upper lip, between the ridges under the nose.

Answer (score -6):

Yes, there is. I believe the pronunciation is the following: *Ahm bro shwah*

The actual word is spelled *embouchure*.  Trumpet players refer to this... (you can spot dentures because they have a flat ahm bro shwah.)

Comment: You're thinking of [embrochure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embouchure), and that refers to the shape of the entire mouth, not simply the upper lip.

Comment: Embouchure, not embrochure.